Problema de Acceso a Archivos en la Caché de Gradle en Android SDK
Estoy enfrentando un problema al intentar construir mi proyecto en Android Studio. El error que aparece es el siguiente:

Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:
C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\caches\transforms-4\86800e8c7037400c9412667439cddd24


Tal vez haya quedado algún programa con el archivo abierto. Luego de reiniciar la máquina tienes el mismo problema? Sin detalles solo podemos hacer sugerencias

si , el mismo problema me sigue saliendo

Puedes eliminar ese archivo?

¿No tendrás los archivos de tu proyecto en una carpeta que se sincroniza con servicios en la nube tipo Google Drive, Dropbox u otros?

Es un problema de sincronización que no deja modificar ese archivo en cache, puedes simplemente cerrar Android Studio y volver a iniciarlo o ir a Build > Rebuild Project.
Si lo anterior no funciona, elimina todo el caché, desde el menú principal ve a:
File > Invalidate Caches and Restart

realice los mismos procedimientos y al momento que esta haciendo la importacion del proyecto me sale lo mismo .

Qué versión de Android Studio usas? Yo nunca había tenido este tipo de problemas hasta estas últimas versiones. Me parece que si realizaste los cambios que comento podría ser el Antivirus que esta causando este problema

android koala 2024.1.1 esa version estoy utilizando.

la última versión al día de hoy!, si probaste con "Invalidate Caches and Restart" y no funcionó, te sugiero hagas la prueba deshabilitando temporalmente el antivirus mientras construyes tu proyecto.
